# how to do simple xsd with netbeans

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd

I need to define some schemes for an API whitch have communication sending and receiving xml strings. I want to document the scheme definition to the clients who will user that API.

for example

```
<store>
<name>the store</name>
    <products>
        <product>
             <id></id>
             <name></name>
             <price></price>
        </product>
        <product>
             <id></id>
             <name></name>
             <price></price>
        </product>
    </products>
</store>
```

So, I cant define the max and min occurrences for product in a products list.
I guess it can be standar-defined in a XSD.

Comment: What are you actually asking for ?

Comment: how to do simple xsds with netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

The XML module for Netbeans doesn't seem to be under active development now, however, take a look at Castor.  Listed among [its features](http://www.castor.org/features.html#Additional-tools) is "XMLInstance2Schema: Ability to create an XML Schema from an XML input document".  You will still have to hand-tweak your XSD but it will give you a good start.